# Correct Spelling: hinzu zu fügen vs. hinzuzufügen

Tags: spelling

I am wondering which way is right to say the following term.

> Sie sind dabei ein Material hinzuzufügen oder zuändern.

or

> Sie sind dabei ein Material hinzu zu fügen oder zu ändern.

Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

Neither of them. Correct is

> Sie sind dabei, ein Material hinzuzufügen oder zu ändern.

For further details [see the section of separable vs inseparable verbs here](https://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_verbs03.htm).